# How to maintain package structure when using schemagen and xjc

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am new to JAX B. I created a project with the structure :

```
src-
    entity-
           Person
    property-
           Address
```

I generate a xsd document using the command

```
C:\workspace\JAXTest\src>schemagen entity\Person.java property\Address.java
```

I see schema1.xsd in src folder now but it does not have any package information. So, If I use xjc to generate classes, I get all the classes in the same folder.

```
C:\workspace\JAXTest\src>xjc schema1.xsd
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
generated\Address.java
generated\ObjectFactory.java
generated\Person.java
```

What can be done so that the xsd can contain the package information so that the generated classes follow the structure of the classes used to create the xsd.

Thanks in advance!

Edit :

There is no particular requirement I am working towards. I am just trying to learn XSD-Class and Class-XSD conversions correctly. Also, I have found that I can use jax customization to specify the global package name but it doesn't work for individual classes. Basically, this does not put my Person in PersonPackage package.

```
<xs:complexType name="person">
  <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <jaxb:package name="PersonPackage"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>    
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="address" type="address" minOccurs="0">
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: May I inquire why you are 1) generating a schema form Java entity classes, and then 2) regenerate the java classes from the generated xsd ? That doesn't seem like what you really want to do. Additionally, you really wouldn't want the XSD to be polluted with implementation-details such as the target java package names, normally when you generate java classes from XSD, you specify this in the .xjb bindings file.

Comment: There is no particular requirement I am working towards. I am just trying to learn XSD-Class and Class-XSD conversions correctly. Also, I have found that I can use jax customization to specify the global package name but it doesn't work for individual classes. Basically, this does not put my Person in PersonPackage package.'<xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <jaxb:package name="PersonPackage"/>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation> '